# Solved GFG question using DP but some test cases are failing

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

I have solved this GFG question using DP but my some test cases are failing. Can anyone please help me to figure out the error?

https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/dice-throw5349/1#

```java
class Solution {

    static long noOfWays(int M, int N, int X) {
        // code here
        long ways[][] = new long[N + 1][X + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= X; j++) {
                ways[i][j] = -1;
            }
        }


        return noOfWaysRec(M, N, X, ways);
    }

    //face lies b/w 1 to M
    static long noOfWaysRec(int M, int N, int X, long[][] ways) {
        if (ways[N][X] != -1) {
            return ways[N][X];
        }
        if (N == 0 || X == 0) {
            if (N == 0 && X == 0) {
                ways[N][X] = 1;
            } else {
                ways[N][X] = 0;
            }
            return ways[N][X];
        }

        int resWays = 0;
        int diceFace = 1;
        //face is mapped to one number less

        while (diceFace <= X && diceFace <= M) {
            ways[N - 1][X - diceFace] = noOfWaysRec(M, N - 1, X - diceFace, ways);
            resWays += ways[N - 1][X - diceFace];
            diceFace++;
        }
        ways[N][X] = resWays;
        return resWays;
    }
};
```

I am getting the following error for this test case. I don't know why it's giving a negative answer and where I am getting wrong.

[image]

Comment: You declared `resWays` as `int` which has to be `long` so that large number such as `7137432446320` won't be a negative value. :)

Comment: @codingmonster thank you so much, didn't notice it.

Comment: you're welcome. I really admire you, i'm not so clever to solve the problems from GFG :(

Comment: @codingmonster you are clever enough to detect the mistake in one go, which itself defines you as a good programmer. Just a little more practice and you'll be able to solve far better than this. I admire you for the passion you have for problem-solving and how you contribute to this community.

Comment: :) thanks for your encouraging comment :-D

Answer (score 0):

According to gfg they want Expected

```
Time Complexity: O(M*N*X)
Expected Auxiliary Space: O(N*X)
```

so we can use DP here

```
class Solution {
    static long[][] dp = new long[51][51];
    static long getNoOfWays(int diceIndex, int sum, int M){
        if(diceIndex < 0)       return (sum == 0) ? 1 : 0; 
        long answer = 0;
        if(dp[diceIndex][sum] != -1)    return dp[diceIndex][sum];
        for(int val = 1; val <= Math.min(sum, M); val++){
            if(sum >= val){
                answer += getNoOfWays(diceIndex - 1, sum - val, M);
            }
        }
        return dp[diceIndex][sum] = answer;
    }
    static long noOfWays(int M , int N , int X) {
        // code here
        for(long[] row : dp)    Arrays.fill(row, -1);
        return getNoOfWays(N - 1, X, M);
    }
};
```